# How to use libacl for udev?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, udev

I try to install udev, but that require libacl. The question is how install/include libacl? I thought it would be enough to download it and put it into the /lib directory. But No.

One Alternative would be to disable libacl in the udev configs. Here is the corresponding text from the READ ME :

```
  - Some udev extras have external dependencies like:
      libacl, libglib2, libusb, usbutils, pciutils, and gperf.
    All these extras can be disabled with configure options.
```

But I don't know how to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

1) No, it's not enough. Can't you use your package manager to install this library (development headers are usually included in package with `-dev` suffix)?

2) To build without libacl pass `--disable-udev_acl` flag to `configure` script:

```
./configure --disable-udev_acl ...
```

In case you want to rebuild debian package: open `debian/rules` file in editor and change `--enable-udev_acl` option (found in `CONFFLAGS_deb` section) to `--disable-udev_acl` and rebuild package normally.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 1) I have a customized Kernel on a target board, that's why I don't use package manager. `./configure --disable-udev_acl` works, but I receive more error. Is there a possibility to find out all dependencies of udev?

Comment: @Peter: build dependency list reported by debian package manager (`apt-rdepends --build-depends --follow=DEPENDS udev`; just for reference): http://pastebin.com/YNsWBbnb